# Is it possible to make a tkinter listbox "entry spot" clickable without moving your mouse when that entry is removed? (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I'm currently working on a problem where I want to be able to move items from one listbox to another easily so that users can pretty easily pick it up. I click on an entry from the listbox and make it move from one listbox to a center listbox, which will then be moved into the opposite listbox when the "MOVE" button is pressed. (I will also let you be able to move the listbox entries from the center back to the starting listbox). My current problem is that when I delete the entry, it will move everything properly, but I will not be able to click on the same exact spot in the listbox I'm clicking on to move the next available entry. (Say I start with the current list of name1... name5. If I click on name1, it will move name1 and name2 will move up. But I cannot immediately click on name2. I have to move my mouse before I can once again click on it) For the purposes of this program, I would like to keep the selectmode to SINGLE, and BROWSE doesn't even solve this issue. Is there a way to make it so that I can click on the same spot while keeping the functionality the same? I have it set up to be how I want it, but this one thing is bugging me and would certainly be annoying for users.

This is a demo of what I am using. As I described above, everything that I've implemented is working as I have intended, but I cannot click on the same spot as I just did without moving my mouse.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Listbox, SINGLE, END, Button

root = Tk()

list_names = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"]

box1 = Listbox(root, selectmode=SINGLE)
box2 = Listbox(root, selectmode=SINGLE)
box1_middle = Listbox(root, selectmode=SINGLE)
box2_middle = Listbox(root, selectmode=SINGLE)


def move():
    while box1_middle.size() > 0:
        box2.insert(END, box1_middle.get(0))
        box1_middle.delete(0)

    while box2_middle.size() > 0:
        box1.insert(END, box2_middle.get(0))
        box2_middle.delete(0)


Button(root, text="MOVE", command=move).grid(row=1, column=1)


def move_box1(event):
    selection = event.widget.curselection()
    if selection:
        index = selection[0]
        data = event.widget.get(index)
        box1.delete(index)
        box1_middle.insert(END, data)


def move_box2(event):
    selection = event.widget.curselection()
    if selection:
        index = selection[0]
        data = event.widget.get(index)
        box2.delete(index)
        box2_middle.insert(END, data)


for name in list_names:
    box1.insert(END, name)

box1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", move_box1)
box2.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", move_box2)

box1.grid(row=1, column=0)
box2.grid(row=1, column=2)
box1_middle.grid(row=0, column=1)
box2_middle.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```